# Is it okay to submit a paper to a conference or publication from another field?

Tags: publications, journals, ethics

For instance, my field is Information Technology and I would like to know if it is okay to submit to management and environmental science publication. Of course, it's not purely I.T. but this is a paper on how I.T. can help preserve the environment, specifically on reducing consumption of resources.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: If your question is "Can someone outside field X submit a paper to a conference in field X?", the answer is "Sure.  Why not?"  If your question is "Can I submit a paper that is not on topic X to a conference on topic X?", the answer is "Sure, but it'll be rejected."  I think your real question is neither of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with submitting to a conference that might not be a perfect fit. I would urge you to ensure that the fit is decent enough that you won't be wasting anyone's time, but cross-polination can be great for both fields.

When I was a graduate student and was helping my advisor review papers for a prominent conference, I read an outstanding paper that I didn't believe was on-topic for the conference, and I suggested to my advisor that it should be rejected it even though it had a novel (and cool) contribution. When I discussed it with her, she said that for really excellent papers, program committees will sometimes be flexible. If I was convinced it was that good, she said, I should give it a positive review and let the committee sort it out. In the end they accepted the paper. It was very well-received at the conference, and the authors were excited to get the paper into the competitive conference, where it would undoubtedly be seen by a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

I think if your work is either *interdisciplinary* (i.e. has impact in two different fields), or at the border of two fields (e.g., physical chemistry or molecular biology), you *should* publish in journals and conferences in a way to address both communities. We usually have a lot to learn by outsiders coming into a given field of research, as they bring a new view, new ideas, concepts and methods. Your case sounds exactly like that, so I'd say go ahead!